# subscribe is not a function - ionic 4

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

Am trying to get some data using api in my ionic 4 project. i followed this guide:

https://ionicacademy.com/http-calls-ionic/

and here my `list.page.ts` :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {

  private selectedItem: any;
  private icons = [
    'flask',
    'wifi',
    'beer',
    'football',
    'basketball',
    'paper-plane',
    'american-football',
    'boat',
    'bluetooth',
    'build'
  ];
  public items: Array<{ title: string; note: string; icon: string }> = [];
  items: Observable<any>;
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient){
    this.item = this.httpClient.get('http://www.fostania.com/api/items/');
this.items.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('my data: ', data);
})
}



  ngOnInit() {
  }
  // add back when alpha.4 is out
  // navigate(item) {
  //   this.router.navigate(['/list', JSON.stringify(item)]);
  // }
}
```

when I try  to access this page it gives me the error :

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.items.subscribe is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have assigned http get observable to `this.item` field. in the next line you should use `this.item`, rather than `this.items` to subscribe to it, and probably save the result like `this.items = data` inside of subscription to handle it later.

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake I did